# DataGridView locked on a inherited UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, inheritance

I have a UserControl with some predefined controls (groupbox,button,datagridview) on it, these controls are marked as protected and the components variable is also marked as protected.

I then want to inherit from this base UserControl to another UserControl, however the DataGridView is always locked in the designer.

I suspect it may have something to do with the DataGridView implementing ISupportInitilize.

```
public class BaseGridDetail : UserControl
```

Has a DataGridView control (et al) defined.

```
public class InheritedDetail : BaseGridDetail
```

The DataGridView control is locked

Does anyone have any ideas how to make this control available in the designer after inheritenace?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By the looks of it, DataListView (and some other controls) do not support visual inheritance.  There's a connect issue [logged here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=116457) which doesn't look hopeful.

There have been similar issues logged with other form controls, e.g. [flowlayoutpanel](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=119442).

I'm unable to find a way to force visual inheritance.

Here's the official answer on [connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=110787): 
"For this particular release, the DataGridView was not designed to be used in visual intheritance. We will keep your suggestion in mind when we plan our future release"
That is of 26/05/2006.

Update: found [this blog post which may have the answer](http://dotnetengineer.wordpress.com/2008/06/27/visual-inheritance-using-datagridview/)

Edit: I was unable to verify the blog post's claims.
Looks like [might be the latest on this issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=284335)

It looks like you can still manipulate the DataListView at runtime though, so you might be able to set visual properties (and other settings).  It's not a great compromise.

Comment: Still there in VS2010: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089289/cannot-visually-change-datagridview-in-inherited-form/15090076#15090076 I also added some extra notes on the .NET profiles.

Answer (score 9):

[1] create Your Custom UserControl

[2] make your custom userControl use the below Inherited DataGridView:

```
[Designer(typeof System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner))]
public class InheritedDataGridView : DataGridView { }
```

[3] Inherit from your Custom UserControl , And viola !!

[4] Ohh dont forget to add "System.Design" dll

Enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

Add the datagrid to a panel control and set the modifiers of the panel and the datagrid to protected. This will all your inherited form design time access to the properties of the grid.

Comment: Good suggestion! This at least lets us position and resize the DataGrid on the child Form. Which often is all one needs.

Comment: Thanks we looked for a solution 4 years ago and did not stumbled with this post until now!

Answer (score 1):

I left an answer but re-read your question and decided to delete it.

What is it about the DataGridView that you're trying to modify in the inherited control? It's columns? I've been able to do this by setting up a protected method in my base UserControl and passing the grid's column collection into it, like this:

```
// in base UserControl
public BaseGridDetail()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    InitGridColumns(dataGridView1.Columns);
}

protected virtual void InitGridColumns(DataGridViewColumnCollection columns)
{
    columns.Clear();
}
```

Now your derived control can simply override that method, like so:

```
// in InheritedDetail
protected override void InitGridColumns(DataGridViewColumnCollection columns)
{
    base.InitGridColumns(columns);
    // add my own custom columns
}
```

Comment: In the designer all the controls can have any of their properties changed, except the DataGridView. It is locked down from the designer perspective completly.

Comment: Yeah - having read Rob's answer to your question, I remembered why I had to go down the "InitGridColumns" path in my own application. Visual inheritence simply doesn't work with DataGridView.

Answer (score -1):

Change property to defined [private] to [protected] defined at xx.designer.cs
which is originally machine generated code.

for example

```
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnSave;
```

to

```
    protected System.Windows.Forms.Button btnSave;
```

and rebuild it.

then you can change the property of inherited control.

Comment: This question is about the DataGridView which does not support visual inheritnace - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/walkthrough-demonstrating-visual-inheritance