# Can I change properties of inherited controls at design time?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, inheritance, visual-inheritance

I am using visual inheritance and was wondering if there is a way to change the properties of inherited controls at design time, preferably in the form designer. If not, then in the designer code.

I have my control declared as Public in the base class. I can access it in the child form code, but not in the form designer. Is this just not possible?

Comment: For those still interested, here explains well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/207549/908336

Answer (score 3):

There are limitations placed within visual studio for visual inheritance.  Unfortunately, derived forms\usercontrols cannot modify controls containing collections within the base, namely DataGridViewRows, ToolStrips, ListViewColumns, etc.

[Microsoft Bug Report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=123288)

There are ways around this in certain situations.  Create a protected property in the base class that exposes the exact properties of the control you wish to modify (DataGridView.BackgroundColor, or ListView.Columns).

Your base form *should* be able access this property to change the components needed.  I've done this for ListView.Columns, and DataGridView.rows successfully, however ToolStrip.Items would not work.

Comment: I got the same situation ,It worked for button but not for toolstripe.

Comment: I wondered why I couldn't get Toolstrip exposed properly - Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems to work only for certain controls, but not all and I can't understand why. On my base form I have a TabControl that within it is a ComboBox, a ToolStrip, and a DataGridView. All of them are set to Public, but I can only modify the properties of the ComboBox and not the other two controls.

I have no idea why this is.

Comment: The designers for ToolStrip and DGV just don't support it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your control visibility. Put the control property Modifiers on public and recompile the project and then you can change properties of the inherited control.

Comment: It seems to work only for certain controls, but not all and I can't understand why. On my base form I have a TabControl that within it is a ComboBox, a ToolStrip, and a DataGridView. All of them are set to Public, but I can only modify the properties of the ComboBox and not the other two controls.