# Cannot visually change DataGridView in inherited form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, inheritance

I have a WinForms form with a `DataGridView` on it. The `DataGridView` is set to `protected`.

When I inherit that form, it is not possible to change the `DataGridView` in the Visual Studio designer. If I do the whole thing with a `Button`, it works as expected.

Is there a way to fix this?

Some (clipped) code (from DatagridForm.Designer.cs):

```
partial class DatagridForm {
    protected DataGridView dgData;
    protected Button button;
}
```

and from Inherited.cs:

```
partial class Inherited : DatagridForm {

}
```

Comment: Can you give us some code, as an example?

Comment: Added some code. The button I can move around with no trouble in the designer of `Inherited`. The `DataGridView` is locked, even though `Locked` is set to `False`.

Comment: This seems to be old: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207504/datagridview-locked-on-a-inherited-usercontrol

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This [blog](http://dotnetengineer.wordpress.com/2008/06/27/visual-inheritance-using-datagridview/) has the solution: just create an inherited user control that points to the right designer stuff:

```
[Designer(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner))]
public class ucInheritedDataGridView : DataGridView { }
```

Works like a charm. Only downside is that you cannot use the .NET Client Profile, because it has no support for System.Forms.Design (you have to add `System.Design` as a reference). This shouldn't be too much of a problem, because the client profile is [deprecated anyway per 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx).

If you really need the client profile, another work around is to wrap the `DataGridView` in a `Panel`, which you can move and resize.