# C# Forms - Can't move inherited control into table

Tags: c#, .net, forms, inheritance, user-controls

Let a user control `A` containing a button `bA` and a user control `AChild` inheriting from `A` and containing a `TableLayoutPanel`.

If I want the inherited button `bA`, within `ChildA`, not to be where it was placed within `A`, but instead be placed in `ChildA`'s `TableLayoutPanel`, how can I do ?

I did change `bA`'s visibility from `private` to `protected`, and it is not `Locked`. But still, when I moved the inherited button `bA` within `ChildA`, it can be moved as expected, but it can NOT be moved inside `ChildA`'s `TableLayoutPanel`. It's like I could move `bA` around, but not change its parent within `ChildA` Why ? Any workaround ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The designer seems like doesn't support this kind of functionality, but you can do that programmatically if you want to.

In the constructor of your AChild control, you can simply add to the tableLayoutPanel1 the button:

```
    public partial class AChild: A
    {
        public AChild()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(bA);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried something similar using SetColumn(), but the change doesn't seem to appear in the designer. I don't know if the designer is only executing the code it has generated or the whole contructor...

Comment: This SO questions says that some controls du not support visual inheritance : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207504/datagridview-locked-on-a-inherited-usercontrol. I guess it works the same for the TableLayoutPanel